# Openshift : how to access particular node if multiple node is there

Tags: openshift

If multiple replicas available in OpenShift for same application then is it possible to access particular instance?

Comment: Yes, use ``oc rsh`` to access the specific pod. To get the list of pods, use ``oc get pods``. This is for getting an interactive shell into the container. If you want to access HTTP port, use port forwarding to the pod using ``oc port-forward``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add dynamically a specific selector on the specific pod  you want to target, and add a service matching this specific selector.
This service will target your specific instance.